# Updating mysqli with Ajax and Jquery is not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

I just want to update or edit `<td>` with Ajax. Edit or Save Button is in a `<td>` and so far everything is woking.

The `Alert()` function also shows variable values but the Ajax portion is not running. I am not sure why the data is not updating. Any help would be appreciated.

**Question_statistics Page**

```
include "include/connection";
while ($records=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    $id=$records['id'];
    $question=$records['question'];
    $question_from=$records['question_from'];
    $question_date=$records['question_date'];
    ?>
    <tr id="record-<?php  echo  $id; ?>" class="record">
        <th scope="row"><?php echo $id; ?></th>
        <!-- Update or Edit -->
        <td class="box" id="box<?php echo $id?>">
            <span class="edit" id="<?php echo $id?>">Edit</span>
            <span class="save" data-table="questions" id="save<?php echo $id?>">Save</span>
            <span id="Q<?php echo $id?>"><?php echo $question; ?></span>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center"><?php echo $question_from; ?></td>
        <td class="text-center"><?php echo $question_date; ?></td>
        <!-- Delete Button -->
        <td align="center">
            <a id="<?php echo $id; ?>" class="delete" data-table="questions">
                <img src="../assets/imgs/delete.png">
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

**Custom javascriptfile:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Update Question  
    $('.edit').click(function(ae){
        ae.preventDefault();
        $('.edit').hide();
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        $('#box'+id).addClass('editable');
        $('#box'+id).attr('contenteditable', 'true');
        $('#save'+id).show();
    });

    $('.save').click(function(){
        $('.save').hide();
        $('.box').removeClass('editable');
        $('.box').removeAttr('contenteditable');
        $('.edit').show();
        // var id =$(this).attr("id"); here id will show like `save+Id`
        var id= $('.edit').attr("id");
        var table = $(this).attr("data-table");
        var question=$('#Q'+id).text();

        alert(id+table+question);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url:'include/ajaxserver.php',
            // data: variable or key : value, key:value, 
            data: {
                id: id,
                edit_me: true,
                table: table,
                question: question
            },
            beforeSend: function() {
                parent.animate({'backgroundColor':'#fb6c6c'},300);
            },
            success: function(data) {
                setTimeout( function ( ) {
                    alert( 'Data has been Deleted From Database' );
                },600 );
            }
        });
    });
});/*end of the ready function*/
```

**ajaxserver file:**

```
include('connection');
if(isset($_GET["edit_me"]) && $_GET["edit_me"]=="true")
{
    $id = $_GET["id"];
    $table = $_GET["table"];
    $question=$_GET["question"];
    $query = "UPDATE `{$table}` SET question='$question' WHERE id='$id'";

    if (mysqli_query($con, $query)) {
        echo "<script>alert('Updated')</script>";
    }
    else
      echo "<script>alert('Not Updated')</script>";
}
```

Comment: first you have a syntax error in ajaxserver file: quite at the end you miss a `{` at `else echo "<script..."`

Comment: second: sending back a `"<script>alert..."` is a bit weird an will not work as you might thing it would.

Comment: third: you are dangerously open to sql injection. Use prepared statements and avoid selecting a table by user input.

Comment: Can You explain SQL injection... I can`t understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice you are checking if `$_GET["edit_me"] == "true"` (string `true`) in the PHP page but that would mean that you should be sending `edit_me: "true"` in your ajax. Change your `$_GET` to:

```
# This will just check the key is filled
if(!empty($_GET["edit_me"]))
```

Then fix the SQL injection (you can Google that) and then send back instead of that javascript alert string you are doing:

```
die(json_encode(['success'=>(mysqli_query($con, $query))]));
```

This would send back to the ajax response `{"success":true}`if it worked. Since you are not specifically expecting json, you can parse the `response`:

```
// I changed the param here from data to response
success: function(response) {
    // Parse the response
    var data = JSON.parse(response);
    // Alert either way
    alert((data.success == true)? "Updated" : "Not Updated");
    // Do whatever this is
    setTimeout( function ( ) {
        alert( 'Data has been Deleted From Database' );
    },600 );
}
```

Comment: Sir.. Thankyou Soo Much... Its working now... Sir can I talk with you separately in future?

Comment: If my answer helped you, please check it off. The reason for this is to let the community know that your question has been answered.

Comment: Yup,, It worked...I post a new question. Can You Check my code and help me?

Comment: I can look at it, but be sure to check off this answer as correct. It will make this answer have the green check mark beside it.